# OpsCenter is having trouble connecting with the agents

Tags: azure, cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am trying to setup a two node cluster in Cassandra. I am able to get my nodes to connect fine as far as I can tell. When I run nodetool status it shows both my nodes in the same data center and same rack. I can also run cqlsh on either node and query data. The second node can see data from the first node, etc.

I have my first node as the seed node both in the Cassandra.yaml and the cluster config file.

To avoid any potential security issues, I flushed my iptable and allowed all on all ports for both nodes. They are also on the same virtual network.

> iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

When I start OpsCenter on either machine it sees both nodes but only has information on the node I am viewing OpsCenter on. It can tell if the other node is up/down, but I am not able to view any detailed information. It sometimes initially says 2 Agents Connected but after awhile it says 1 agent failed to connect. It keeps prompting me to install OpsCenter on the other node although it's already there.

The OpsCenterd.log doesn't reveal much. There don't appear to be any errors but I see INFO: Nodes with agents that appear to no longer be running .

I am not sure what else to check as everything but OpsCenter seems to be working fine.

Comment: This says to install OpsCenter on each node in the cluster and I have seen other posts saying the same: http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/how-to-set-up-and-monitor-a-multi-node-cassandra-and-hadoop-cluster-on-linux

Comment: What's also odd is that my address.yaml is practically empty. It has only one setting for stomp_interface yet the documentation shows there being lots of settings that should already be in there.

Comment: I followed your link and it says: "With DataStax OpsCenter, you’ll install the main OpsCenter service on one of your nodes and agents on every node" - you only install opscenter once. From the GUI, you will be prompted to install the agents on the other nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far! I tried your instructions but no luck. I hard to create a whole new node because the old one was hosed after uninstalling opscenter. I created the new node and everything is connecting fine but OpsCenter won't work.

Comment: I take that back. It just started working. I guess it took a bit to refresh. Thanks!

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites Additionally, you can setup a failover OpsCenter server on a secondary server.  You can configure the failover server via instructions [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/configFailover.html), to clarify on LHWizard's comment.  You shouldn't run two active opscenter installations, but configuring a failover server is within the best practices.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites - would you like me to put my comment as an answer so that you can approve it?

Comment: sure, that would be good

Comment: EDIT - corrected the configuration file name. 
The first thing is - you should never try to manage your cluster with multiple opscenter installs. uninstall the additional copies of opscenter. in address.yaml, set stomp_interface to the opscenter ip address and restart the agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install Opscenter on a single node rather than all nodes. The opscenter gui will then prompt you to install the agent on each of the nodes in the cluster. Use `nodetool status` or `nodetool ring` to make sure that the cluster is properly functioning and all nodes are Up and functioning Normally. (status = UN)

In address.yaml file you can set stomp_address equal to the ip address of the opscenter server to force the agents to the correct address.

Comment: Can you clarify... You said early Opscenter gets set in datastax-agent-env.sh. Does it get set there or the address.yaml?

Comment: I double-checked the [datastax docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html) to be sure, and yes, stomp_address is set in address.yaml file. I'll correct my earlier comment.

Comment: When I add a new node (CentOS 6.5) in opscenter from the GUI, it get successfully added but on refreshing the opscenter page, I get the error for the newly added node, "The DataStax Agent must be connected and running on each node in order for OpsCenter functionality to work properly."
The nodetool ring and nodetool status and give the desired result and the stomp_address on the new node also states that the storm_address is set to the node where opscenter server is installed. Is there anything else which can be done?